# Como inserir e executar parâmetros em uma procedure no oracle 11g no vb6

Tags: oracle, visual-basic-6

```
PROCEDURE        pr_consulta_rg_site (
p_rg_cidadao in varchar2,
p_dt_nascimento in varchar2,
p_rg_cidadao_o out varchar2,
p_no_cidadao_o out varchar2,
p_dt_nascimento_o out varchar2,
p_dt_expedicao_o out varchar2,
p_texto_o out varchar2
) as
   w_count number;
   w_count_del number;
   w_count_bloq number;
   w_rg_cidadao number;
   w_teste_data varchar2(10);
   abandona exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se essa referência ajuda:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15222/How-to-Use-Stored-Procedures-in-VB
e http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_comm_createparameter.asp

Comment: Você deve escrever aqui os trechos mais relevantes do link que resolvem a questão do OP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inclua o pacote nuget `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` em seu projeto (Este é um `driver` de conexão com o banco de dados `Oracle`).
2. Importar essas duas namespaces em seu código:

```
Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types
```

3. Para criar um parametro faça da seguinte forma:

```
Dim rgCidadaoParameter As OracleParameter = oracleCommand.CreateParameter()
rgCidadaoParameter.ParameterName = "p_rg_cidadao"
rgCidadaoParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
rgCidadaoParameter.Size = 4096
rgCidadaoParameter.Value = "1.111.111"
oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(rgCidadaoParameter)
```

Você pode ainda alterar a "direção" do seu parametro para indicar se é do tipo `IN`, `OUT` ou `RETURNVALUE` (Que serve para receber valores de `functions`).

Este é o valor padrão e serve para parametros do tipo `IN`:

```
rgCidadaoOutParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
```

Para `OUT`:

```
rgCidadaoOutParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

Para retornos de funções:

```
rgCidadaoOutParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue.
```

Abaixo um exemplo pratico baseado na sua pergunta:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=banco;User ID=usuario;Password=senha;"

Using oracleConnection As OracleConnection = New Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionString)

    oracleConnection.Open()

    Dim oracleCommand As OracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand()
    oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    oracleCommand.CommandText = "pr_consulta_rg_site"

    Dim rgCidadaoParameter As OracleParameter = oracleCommand.CreateParameter()
    rgCidadaoParameter.ParameterName = "p_rg_cidadao"
    rgCidadaoParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    rgCidadaoParameter.Size = 4096
    rgCidadaoParameter.Value = "1.111.111"
    oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(rgCidadaoParameter)

    Dim rgCidadaoOutParameter As OracleParameter = oracleCommand.CreateParameter()
    rgCidadaoOutParameter.ParameterName = "p_rg_cidadao_o"
    rgCidadaoOutParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    rgCidadaoParameter.Size = 4096
    rgCidadaoOutParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

    oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(rgCidadaoOutParameter)

    Dim result As Int32 = oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim rgCidadaoOut As OracleString = rgCidadaoOutParameter.Value
    Console.WriteLine(rgCidadaoOut.Value)

End Using
```